# Fine Uploader - Add Blob (canvas.toDataURL) - Upload to S3

Tags: canvas, amazon-s3, blob, fine-uploader, todataurl

My page makes  a copy of the users html5 canvas on a click of a button with:

```
var canvasData;

$( "#button" ).click(function() {
    canvasData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    // upload canvasData here...
});
```

I now need to upload this to my s3 bucket with fine-uploader. In the docs it mentions i can upload blob with:

```
addBlobs (canvasData[, params[, endpoint]]);
```

How best would I integrate this to save and get the the tempLink back? Would i use the S3 structure as below with signature,request etc as i would a normal selected file? How does this link in with `addBlobs`?

```
$("#fine-uploader").fineUploaderS3({
    request: {
        endpoint: '{ YOUR_BUCKET_NAME }.s3.amazonaws.com'
        accessKey: '{ YOUR_ACCESS_KEY }'
    },
    signature: {
        endpoint: '/s3/signature'
    },
    uploadSuccess: {
        endpoint: '/s3/success'
    },
    iframeSupport: {
        localBlankPagePath: '/success.html'
    }
}).on('complete', function(event, id, name, response) {
    if (response.success) {
        console.log(response.tempLink);
    }
});
```

Comment: The addBlobs method docs do not mention canvasData.  You must pass a `Blob` or the described wrapper to that method.

Comment: Why are you turning the canvas to a Data URI?  What are you doing with the canvas beforehand?

Comment: The user uploads a photo (with your fine uploader s3 uploader) that gets loaded into a canvas where they can manipulate it, add text and draw over the top. I then use `canvas.toDataURL` to get the data and later save it as a png. I need to take this and upload it fine uploader s3 if possible?

Comment: @odd_duck You should voice your support of: [#1198](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/1198). It sounds like a feature you could use :)

Comment: @MarkFeltner fully agree, would be a highly valuable feature. Was able to achieve this without using fine-uploader but would like to see this introduced

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use the `toBlob` method on the canvas element.  However, this does not have wide browser support.  [Perhaps we will expose the internal code that converts a canvas to a blob at some point](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/1198) (vote on this case).  For now, you can have a [look at how this is done in the scaling module](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/blob/8eb2749c92d4510589150a2003620d8d1ff73fe1/client/js/scaling/scaler.js#L404), and use this in your web app to convert the canvas to a blob.

To summarize:

1. If `toBlob` is present on the `HTMLCanvasElement` use that to convert the canvas to a blob.  Skip to Step 6.
2. If `toBlob` is not available, convert the canvas to a data URI
3. Decode the base64 portion of the data URI using `atob`.
4. Convert the decoded base64 string to a typed array
5. Use the blob constructor or (for older browsers) `BlobBuilder` to turn the typed array to a blob.
6. Pass the blob to Fine Uploader's `addBlobs` method.

Comment: Thanks for this Ray. Once i have the blob - how would i construct this for the s3 upload. Would the `addBlobs` method fit into the fineUploaderS3 setup (as in opening question and getting started guides) or is it done differently? Have you got an example?

Comment: `$("#fine-uploader").fineUploader("addBlobs", blob);`

Comment: In the end i just did an ajax upload on the canvas.toDataURL, did a base64_decode on the posted data and then generated a pre-signed url without using fine-uploader  Seemed the easier solution and it meant it has a wider compatibility for browsers. Definitely agree on the #1198 ticket that Mark mentioned as i think fine-uploader is a great product. Thanks for your possible solution though too

Comment: @Ray Nicholus it try on submit ("#fine-uploader").fineUploader("addBlobs", blob); No files to upload.